# If $A\cap B^\complement=\emptyset$ then $A\cap B=A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I need help with this excercise.

If $A\cap B^\complement=\emptyset$ then $A\cap B=A$

---

I try

$$A\cap B^\complement =\emptyset$$
$$(A\cap B^\complement)\cap B =\emptyset \cap B$$
$$A\cap (B^\complement\cap B )= B$$
$$A=B$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: $B^c\cap B=\emptyset$?

Comment: Your reasoning fails because $∅∩= ∅$ for any set $B$

Answer (score 3):

No, your reasoning leads nowhere because you get $\emptyset=\emptyset$. The property you want is a direct consequence of
$$
A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c). 
$$

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\in A$, you have $x\not \in B^c$.

$\implies$For every $x\in A$, you have $x\in B$.

$\implies$ $A\subseteq B$

$\implies A\cap B=A$

Answer (score 0):

You can use also
$$A\cap B^\complement=\emptyset \Rightarrow A \subset B \Leftrightarrow A\cap B=A$$